# get all the td's except the first

Tags: html, css

I have this structure:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to use css in order to give border to all the td's except the first.
I cannot add class attributes to the structure.

How can I do that?

Comment: What browsers do you need to be compatible with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`:first-child`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html), but [note the rudimentary support in IE (not supported in IE 5.5 and IE 6 at all)](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t17).

```
table tr td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table tr td:first-child {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Additionally, if you absolutely need IE 6 compatibility, you can use javascript to apply a different class to the first child of a `<tr>`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the CSS 3 ~ selector? It is supported by ie7 and above + all the other major browsers. "td ~ td" would select all td elements with a previous td element as a sibling.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selector_sibling.html

I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: I prefer to work with the common solution that will work with all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try selectivizr.com to use `:first-child` in IE.